# Why is my dictionary not in numeric order, and can I change the delimeters?

Tags: python, dictionary

I had to make two dictionaries dictionary of compounds from a text file. They're listed in numeric order in the text file, from C00001 to C20990 (C means compound), however, when I go to print the dictionaries, everything comes out messily, and not in numeric order. How can I change that? Also, is there a way to put a double quote on the left side of the key, and the other double quote on the right side of the value string? And, separately, when I try to print it so that it has a new row for every key, it tells me I have a key error (specifically for entry C20990. I'd assume that this is because it's the last one in the dictionary, but that would only happen if it was already in numeric order, which it's not, so it makes me worry that during the for loop at the end, it'll happen with more entries)

```
import sys
entries = []
names = []
a = {} #achiral
c = {} #chiral
for line in file:
    if line.startswith("ENTRY"):
        s = line[5:len(line)]
        s = s.split()
        entries.append(s[0])

    if line.startswith("NAME"):
        s = line[4:len(line)]
        s = s.strip()
        st = "".join(s+" ")

        line=next(file)
        check = False
        while not line.startswith("FORMULA") and not line[0].isalpha():
            s = line.strip()
            if s.find("(R)")>=0:
                check = True
            if s.find("(S)")>=0:
                check = True
            if s.find("L-")>=0:
                check = True
            if s.find("D-")>=0:
                check = True
            st+=s+" "
            line = next(file)

        st = st.strip()
        if not check:
            a[entries[-1]] = st
        else:
            c[entries[-1]] = st
        names = []
        st = ""
for key in c:
    print("{0}: {1}".format(key, c[entries[-1]]))
```

Comment: You could use the `sortedDict` class at http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When I go to print the dictionaries, everything comes out messily, and not in numeric order. How can I change that?

   Python dictionary use a hash table to index all the keys in an unordered way. Plus, the key you are using like `C20990` is a `string`, although you can easily extract the digits and convert them to an `int`.

   I suggest you do this when you add it to the entry, namely in the first `if` clause, use

   ```
   s = s.split()
   s = int(s[1:])
   ```

   And sort your keys before printing out the entry

   ```
   for key in sorted(c.keys()):
   ```
2. Also, is there a way to put a double quote on the left side of the key, and the other double quote on the right side of the value string?

   Yes, use the [output formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).
3. And, separately, when I try to print it so that it has a new row for every key, it tells me I have a key error (specifically for entry C20990).

   You use `c[entries[-1]]`, but this entry may be a achiral and belong to dictionary `a`. You need to use the keys of `c` instead, see code in Q1.

Comment: I'm new to programming, so I guess I don't exactly get what I'm supposed to do for #3 there. Can you explain?

Comment: @Kevin You can print the dictionary `c` and `a` separately using method in @Hesham Attia's answer. And if you want to print the keys as in `entries`, you need to test if the key is in `a` or `c` using `if entries[i] in a`. Checkout the `dict` and `list` types in `Python` if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries are unordered. You could sort them before printing.

```
for key, value in sorted(c.items()):
   print("{0}: {1}".format(key, value))
```

I am not sure why you're getting the key error, but it could be added to the dict `a` instead of `c`.

Answer (score 0):

A Python `dict` is an unsorted container implemented as a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).  Hashing strings “randomizes” their order.  And even *this* order won't be preserved when actually inserting them into a hashed structure.

```
>>> sorted(string.ascii_uppercase, key=hash)
['G', 'Z', 'M', 'V', 'L', 'K', 'C', 'J', 'P', 'N', 'D', 'O', 'Q', 'F', 'S', 'R', 'W', 'E', 'X', 'A', 'Y', 'B', 'I', 'U', 'H', 'T']
>>> set(_)
{'F', 'M', 'B', 'W', 'G', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'X', 'R', 'K', 'E', 'N', 'V', 'U', 'Q', 'T', 'Z', 'S', 'I', 'L', 'P', 'J', 'H', 'Y', 'O'}
```

If you want to sort the keys, then explicitly sort them:

```
for key in sorted(c.keys()):
    print("{0}: {1}".format(key, c[entries[-1]]))
```